# IpTables Rules for sending Mails on linux server

Tags: linux, firewall

Below are rules for Firewall (Refered from multiple posts) settings, where I want to allow Sending Mails through Applications on my server and allow FTP access of Server. But the Mails have Stopped passing through application after adding these rules. may be something is missing in this. Any help is Appreciated.

```
*filter

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [824:72492]

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 20:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 20:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

The Console Error I get for this is,
email Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want that REJECT rule to be at the end of the INPUT chain. I.e., moved to be the last rule before COMMIT.